# How to write a SQL query to get sum of transactions?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I want sql query for this . I have three tables customer,account, transaction
the schema of the are as below[image]

I want to get customer details, account id, sum of transaction id[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  This looks like a pretty basic `JOIN`/`GROUP BY` query.

Comment: I started learning sql recently and i tried this by below query .  SELECT
  Customer.customer_id
  Account.Account_id,
  SUM(Transaction.transaction_amount) as amount
FROM
  Account
INNER JOIN
  Customer
ON
  Account.customer_id= Customer.customer_id
INNER JOIN
   Transaction
ON
  Account.account_id = Transaction.account_id
GROUP BY
  Account.account_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is quite close.  Try this:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, a.Account_id, SUM(t.transaction_amount) as amount
FROM Account a INNER JOIN
     Customer c
     ON a.customer_id = c.customer_id INNER JOIN
     Transaction t
     ON a.account_id = t.account_id
GROUP BY c.customer_id, a.account_id;
```

Note the use of table aliases to simplify the query.  And --  more importantly -- the `SELECT` columns and `GROUP BY` columns are consistent.

Because the `customer_id` is in the `Account` table, you don't need the `Customer` table.  So, you can simplify this to:

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.Account_id, SUM(t.transaction_amount) as amount
FROM Account a INNER JOIN
     Transaction t
     ON a.account_id = t.account_id
GROUP BY a.customer_id, a.account_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Sum the transactions grouped by CustomerID and then join to the customers table on the CustomerID like this:

```
SELECT c.Customer_name, c.Customer_mobile, t.Transaction_sum
FROM Customer c
JOIN (
    SELECT t.CustomerID, SUM(t.Sum) as Transaction_sum
    FROM transactions t
    GROUP BY t.CustomerID
    ) t on t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
```